# nextjs+dockercompose: env variables pass to nextjs.config.js

Tags: docker-compose, next.js

I have a `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  .........
  env: {
    BASE_URL: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000',
  },
  ............
};
```

If I want to change the `BASE_URL` while building docker image I can do

my `Dockerfile` file

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN yarn install

ENV BASE_URL=http://yy.yyy.yy.yy:80

# Copy all files
COPY ./ ./

RUN yarn build
```

SO ENV BASE_URL=http://yy.yyy.yy.yy:80 in your docker file will set an environment variable BASE_URL to it's value, you need to read it for that variable.

```
//next.config.js
module.exports = {
  .........
  env: {
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000', //read the value from env id empty use default value.
  },
  ............
};
```

But how can I make this image more generic, So that while running the service in dockercompose i can pass the BASE_URL

Is that possible.

Else for every different BASE_URL, i have to create different images.